# What kind of join between 2 SQL table that they don't have common id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a SQL table consists of id, name, email,.... I have another SQL table that has id, email, emailstatus but these 2 id are different they are not related. The only thing that is common between these 2 tables are emails.

I would like to join these 2 tables bring all the info from table1 and if the email address from table 1 and table 2 are same and emailstatus is 'Bounced'. But the query that I am writing gives me more record than expected.

Can you help? Also I am not even sure that it is the right thing to do without a common id. This is my query.

```
 SELECT
 A.[Id]
,A.[Application]
,A.[Loan]
,A.[Firstname]
,A.[Lastname]
,A.[Email],
,H.[Email], H.[EmailStatus] as BouncedEmail 
FROM Applicant A (NOLOCK)

left outer join [tbl_Webhook] [H] (NOLOCK)
 on A.Email = H.Email

 and  A.Email is not Null and H.Email is not Null and H.[EmailStatus]='bounced'
```

sample Desired Data:

```
id    email                    name              emailFromTable2        emailstatus
 1     test2@yahoo.com           lili      test2@yahoo.com        bounced
 2     tesere@yahoo.com          mike             Null                Null
 3     tedfd2@yahoo.com          nik           tedfd2@yahoo.com       bounced
 4     tdfdft2@yahoo.com         sam               Null              Null              
 5     tedft2@yahoo.com          james     tedft2@yahoo.com       bounced
 6     tedft2@yahoo.com          San              Null
```

Comment: Seems like inner join should suffice (common email is as good as common id, if we ignore performance issues), and null checks are not needed here.

Comment: This is using SQL Server syntax so I attached that label.

Comment: Can you give sample data and desired results?  I cannot figure out exactly what you mean by "I would like to join these 2 tables bring all the info from table1 and if the email address from table 1 and table 2 are same and emailstatus is 'Bounced'".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your root question is:

"Find out whether every record in Applicant has ever had a bounced email."

The following query should get you your desired output (NULL values when not bounced, 'bounced' otherwise).

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, A.email, B.emailstatus
FROM Applicant A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT email, emailstatus
    FROM tbl_webhook
) B
ON A.email = B.email
AND B.emailstatus = 'bounced'
```

Some Notes:

- Joining on a non id field is fine. The only thing you might need to consider is performance (as id fields tend to be either the primary key or part of the primary key). I wouldn't worry too much about this, unless you notice that its causing a problem. Introducing an index on email for both tables would help if it turns out to be a problem.
- Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN with B.emailstatus = 'bounced' ensures that only rows where emailstatus is bounced are included in the join (meaning even though john@test.com has an email status, he still shows up as NULL in the result set, because his status isn't 'bounced').
- SQL Fiddle (link below) is a fantastic way of communicating SQL problems to people over the internet.
- Use DISTINCT to remove identical rows. This will stop you from getting multiple identical records as a result of the multiple bounced emails records in tbl_webhook.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Applicant (id int, name varchar(10), email varchar(100))

INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES(1, 'John', 'john@test.com')
INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES(2, 'Bob', 'bob@test.com')
INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES(3, 'Mary', 'mary@test.com')
INSERT INTO Applicant VALUES(4, 'Jane', 'jane@test.com')

CREATE TABLE tbl_Webhook (id varchar(2), email varchar(100), emailstatus varchar(10))

INSERT INTO tbl_Webhook VALUES('AA', 'john@test.com', 'received')
INSERT INTO tbl_Webhook VALUES('BB', 'bob@test.com', 'bounced')
INSERT INTO tbl_Webhook VALUES('CC', 'mary@test.com', 'sent')
```

Comment: @ Todd thanks for your response I exactly try this too but again I get more record, before join I have 209694 record and after I get 532319. How I can get same number of record, means if for the data is existed in table 1 there is data in table 2 show the  data otherwise I don't need table2 data shown.

Comment: If you are receiving more records after the LEFT OUTER JOIN, then that means there must be multiple rows in `tbl_webhook` for each row in `Applicant` (which makes sense). What question are you trying to answer? Are you asking whether or not an applicant has EVER had an email bounce, or how many bounces they've had?

Comment: @ Todd only it is important that there is any bounces email so one time is ok because I only need to found the email addresses that are bounded.

Comment: I've updated my answer taking this new information into account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, now when I run query without join I have 209694 record when I add join and Distinct at the top I have 209680. not sure why 14 less record, I need to have exact same number of record that I had before the join. I guess I need to use distinct on the second table but not sure how.

Comment: It sounds like you have duplicates in your Applicant table, which are being removed during the DISTINCT. Is that possible? If you absolutely must have the same number of rows at the end, try my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `H.[EmailStatus] = 'bounced' OR H.[EmailStatus] IS NULL` to the WHERE clause. This should give you the desired result.
In `OUTER JOIN`s join condition is not the same as the filter condition in the `WHERE` clause

EDIT: Updated the condition so that rows without a status get pulled into the result set.

Comment: I tried that before, then it only give me columns that has email and emailstatus in second table, it does not return me any data from 1st table that doesn't have record in second table.

Comment: @nikta as Gordon has suggested please provide some sample data to receive more help.

Comment: Add an `OR H.[emailStatus] IS NULL` to the WHERE clause if you only want rows that do not have a status in the second table or have a bounced status.

Comment: that is what I have:                                            left outer join [tbl_Webhook] [H] (NOLOCK)
 on A.Email = H.email
 and H.[EmailStatus]='Bounced'                                           where  H.[emailStatus] is null

Comment: But before join I have 209694 record and after join I have  205729 I think I have to have same record number.

Comment: @nikta Not so if there are other email statuses in the second table.

Comment: @nikta Also from you previous comment, that will pull only records that have a null value in the emailStatus field.